# Añadir un objeto luego de un jsonapi serializer en ruby on rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

quiero hacer algo así como un "merge" de un objeto token justo después de un serializer, pero pese a que pude hacerlo, el json del serializer devuelve una sola linea con todo el objeto en vez de estar formateado como es usual. Esto es lo que devuelve:

```json
{
    "users": "{\"data\":{\"id\":\"20\",\"type\":\"user\",\"attributes\":{\"first_name\":\"Testo\",\"last_name\":\"Testo\",\"email\":\"testo9@testo.comssrre456dd\",\"photo\":null}}}",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyMH0sImV4cCI6MTYzODMwNTMyOH0.TP_ktgIG4hn4oVfEcT6c8qDDNw-m60IpdITT36aRdnE"
}
```

y este es el código del controlador

```rb
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.role = Role.create_or_find_by(name: 'admin', description: 'admin user')

    if @user.save
      token = AuthTokenService.call(@user.id)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { 
          render :json => {
            "users" => UserSerializer.new(@user).serializable_hash.to_json,
            "token" => token
          }
        }
      end
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

cómo puedo hacer para que devuelva el serializer formateado como es debido?
PD: La gema utilizada es jsonapi serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de `UserSerializer.new(@user).serializable_hash.to_json`, deberías usar  simplemente `UserSerializer.new(@user).serializable_hash`

Comment: Genial eso me sirvió! Ahora devuelve el objeto bien formateado

Comment: no me deja ya que me dice que no tengo 15 de reputación